# How can I escape the wildcard for like operator?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let us suppose that I intend to search for `50%` inside a textual value. I would like to use the `like` operator, like this:

```
select ID
from prices
where description like '%50%%'
```

but the system cannot distinguish the `%` just after the `50` from the other % characters. I would like to escape it, like this:

```
select ID
from prices
where description like '%50\%%'
```

but it will not find elements then. So how should I proceed?

Comment: try like '%50[%]%'

Comment: @SolStein, thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for. Can you formulate an answer so I can thank you by accepting it?

Comment: it seems someone marked it as duplicate, so i cannot place an answer anymore, please upvote the comment.

Comment: Sure. It seems the question was a duplicate indeed.